# Views don't get injected by AndroidAnnotations in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-annotations

The @ViewById annotations are not working in my DialogFragment.

I use `@EFragment(R.layout.mydialogfragment)`

I create the fragment by doing

`MyDialogFragment_.builder()
  .build()
  .init(someObject, new ClickListener() {...})
  .show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");`

where `init()` is my custom method which returns the `MyDialogFragment` for chaining.

I didn't override `OnCreateDialog`, nor did I override `onCreateView`, and I'm not using any of the `@After...` annotations of AndroidAnnotations.

I'm trying to use the injected views in my `init()` method, but they are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I finished typing the question I realized what was wrong. I was assuming views would be injected by the time `build()` returned so I could use them in the `init()` method, but they weren't. The fix was to annotate another method with the `@AfterViews` annotation and do the view related initialization there.

Answer (score 0):

How can I create my DialogFragment with AA:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.my_fragment_layout) public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

  @ViewById TextView myTextView;
  @ViewById Button myButton;

  public static MyDialogFragment_ newInstance() {
    MyDialogFragment_ f = new MyDialogFragment_();
    return f;
  }

  @AfterViews void init() {
    // something
  }

}
```

How can I start it?

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```